# run config-block inside formtastic or simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, formtastic

How can I call and run a predefined config-block with formtastic or simple_form elements: What I did so far:

Create the form-config (in this case with formtastic):

```
AppmeConfig.register App do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do 
      f.input :category
      f.input :slug
    end
    f.action :submit
  end
end
```

Assign the Block to the template:

```
def form &block
  @form = block
end
```

In the template i do the following:

```
=semantic_form_for(@resource, &@form)
```

Everything fine so far and the source runs ... but it only outputs **the last element** (in this case the action button). Can you give me a hint, what's wrong?

More Information: the output is exactly the same for formtastic and simple_form, it doesn't work as well with a normal .html.erb-template instead of .haml

Answer (score 0):

Not that nice as expected, but for the first I came up this solution (ok sorry, it's a dirty hack):

```
=simple_form_for @resource do |f|
  - @form.to_source(:strip_enclosure => true).to_s.split("\n").each do |line|
    = eval(line)
```

Explanation of the code above: I used sourcify to parse the whole block and eval it in the context of the form.

The main-problem I found is with the build in form_for-helper of rails, that doesn't accept block input. I'm wrong?